# I would like to modify the output of Webgl Platform Building with Unity3D

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Building with WebGL creates one HTML file and one Build folder.

Remove the Build/Aa.json file from here orIt should be modified to js.

Now I'm trying to put json's content in HTML but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | TyphoonFloodRiskAssessment</title>
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
    var json = {
"companyName": "aaaaa",
"productName": "aa",
"dataUrl": "aa_Build.data.unityweb",
"wasmCodeUrl": "aa_Build.wasm.code.unityweb",
"wasmFrameworkUrl": "aa_Build.wasm.framework.unityweb",
"TOTAL_MEMORY": 268435456,
"graphicsAPI": ["WebGL 2.0", "WebGL 1.0"],
"webglContextAttributes": {"preserveDrawingBuffer": false},
"splashScreenStyle": "Dark",
"backgroundColor": "#231F20"
};
var data = JSON.parse(json);
      var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", 
      data
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 1012px; height: 650px; margin: auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The content of "var = json" is the content of aa.json.

How can you solve it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: You are about to upload a Webgl Build file to the server.
However, the server's policy is that it can't upload the "json" file
So it should be revised.

Comment: thats weird considering json is just text why would any server refuse it

Comment: I don't know that either.
json file is not uploadable and js can upload.
Is there a way to modify it?

Comment: well Im sure you can merge them if you wish, but you need to keep everything valid

Comment: By the way, is the code above wrong when json is text?

Comment: Im going to guess there are java errors, but because its expecting the json variable to be string so it can parse it, and you provided an array it maybe there..

Comment: Js file was created and solved without json in html.